# org.springframework.orm.hibernate4 alternate for spring hibernateTemplate?

Tags: hibernate

In Hibernate3 I am using

```
String[] paramNames = {PARAMS};
Object[] values = { VALUES};
Collection coll= this.getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam(Person.QUERY_STATUS, paramNames, values);
```

But Now I have to use hibernate 4.1.1. But org.springframework.orm.hibernate4 does not support hibernateTemplate. How to do this now? Please advice..

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for HibernateTemplate in SPring 3.1 and Hibernate 4, so you should use native Hibernate API.

> HibernateTemplate isn't recommended for use anymore (about since the
>   release of hibernate 3.0.1) there is no more added value so that isn't
>   going to be in there anymore for hibernate 4. Simply use the plain
>   SessionFactory and use the getCurrentSession method to obtain the
>   current transactional session (don't use openSession!!!!) and you are
>   good to go...